# How to force caching CSS/JS changes in live websites using google chrome that won't change with reloading pages?

Tags: google-chrome, caching

I want to make some effects on live websites I visit. Like removing a banner or changing a background or testing some JS on them while websites are live and want these changes applied even after reloading pages.

Comment: Are you asking for a library like http://tampermonkey.net/ ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was asking for. Thank you